# Using icons from NX shares assets lib in project's styles url attribute value

Tags: angular, assets, monorepo, nrwl-nx

In my monorepo I implemented `NX shared assets library` for storing icons. This lib can be used across multiple applications inside this monorepo. This mentioned librabry contains set of svg icons and some angular directives. Icons are copied into project's assets folder within serve/build using `project.json` definition like this:

```
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*.svg",
    "input": "./libs/shared/ui-model-icon/src/icons",
    "output": "/assets/icons/model-icons"
  },
  ...
]
```

And it is working well when i try to refer to those icons from template or from typescript (to set some element's css styles like background-image or so)

The problem is when i tried to refer to those assets icons from project's scss styles file like this:

```
  .imei {
    background-image: url("/../assets/icons/model-icons/person.svg");
  }
```

Angular CLI wont build/run application because scss processor can't resolve file "person.svg" which in fact do not exists in assets before build/serve. Build ends up with error:
 `Can't resolve './assets/icons/model-icons/person.svg'`

Is there any way to set this up (using project.json configuration i hope) so i can use shared assets icons within scss style files?

I tried to add this into project.json without any success

```
  "implicitDependencies": ["shared-ui-model-icon"],
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "assets": [{
          "glob": "**/*.svg",
          "input": "./libs/shared/ui-model-icon/src/icons",
          "output": "/assets/icons/model-icons"
        }],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "./libs/shared/ui-model-icon/src/icons"
          ]
        }
      },
    }
  },
```

Also tried the solution to change css url into form like this (stating with ^):

```
background-image: url("^/../assets/icons/model-icons/person.svg");
```

In this form im able to build application but scss file underline all parts of this url and mark it as invalid url `Cannot resolve directory 'assets'` . Why is it working with `^` at the beginning of the url and what it means?